# Issue with Sum of Odd Numbers Code

Tags: python

I know that there are other post on this and I have referred to them but I can't seem to figure this one out.

This code gives me the value 2500, just 2500.

```
sum = 0;
for i in range (1,100):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        sum = sum + i;
print (sum)
```

However I want the range to vary. So I came up with this

```
def odd_sum_n(n):
    sum = 0;
    for i in range(1,2*n):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            sum = sum + i;
    print (sum)

print(odd_sum_n(5))
```

But this code gives me the solution

```
25
None
```

I kept trying to adjusting this code but I don't see why the "None" appears. I'm new to python so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: sum of first `n` odd numbers is `n^2`

Comment: You can also set the step of your range by doing `range(1, 2 * n, 2)`, which will go `1, 3, 5...`.

Answer (score 7):

Python considers that the return code is `None` for functions not returning anything

You actually have to *return* sum not *print* it in your function

```
def odd_sum_n(n):
    sum = 0;
    for i in range(1,2*n):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            sum += i;
    return (sum)

print(odd_sum_n(5))
```

BTW I would suggest to avoid using `sum` as it is a predefined function...

Note: another solution, shorter where we use prefedined `sum`

```
def odd_sum_n(n):
    return sum(range(1,2*n,2))

print(odd_sum_n(5))
```

for laughs: hjpotter92 comment is even better for this particular problem

```
def odd_sum_n(n):
    return n*n
```

another classic serie: sum of all integers from 1 to n => `sum(range(n))` but also `n*(n+1)//2`

Answer (score 1):

you want to get the value from your `def odd_sum_n(n)` for that you need to `return(sum)` and then just `print(odd_sum_n(n))` this will only print your answer.
 you are getting `none` because you are trying to print two times one time in `def` and other time in when you calling the `function` it self. hope this helps you why you were getting `none` in your result.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning any value from your odd_sum(n) function that's why it print None.

Answer (score 0):

This program illustrates why you get `2500` printed

```
def print2500():
  print(2500)

print2500()
```

And this one why you get `None` printed

```
def doNotReturnAnything():
  n = 2500

print(doNotReturnAnything())
```

Combine both and you get exactly the same result as in the Opening Question :

```
def print2500():
  print(2500)

print(print2500())
```

And finally the correct way to do it, have the function return a value.

```
def return2500():
  return 2500

print(return2500())
```

Try them yourself!